# Pointer arithmetic - counting dots

Tags: c

Can't get any of the if statements to trigger and print something in the main. I am confused on what to do from here.

Can you please find where I have gone wrong for this problem. I need to count the number of dots and dashes (I've simplified it to work on the dots first).

The question must be solved using pointer arithmetic and the function has been provided

```
void analyse(char* code, int* p_dots, int* p_dashes);
```

^

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void analyse(char* code, int* p_dots)
{
char *current = code;
int k = 0;

if ((*current + k) == '.')
{
    p_dots++;
    k++;
}
if ((*current + k) == '-')
{
    //p_dashes++;
    k++;
}
if ((*current + k) ==' ')
{
    //p_dashes++;
    k++;
}
}

int main(void)
{
char* morse[] =
{
    "... --- ..."                           // SOS
//  "-- --- .-. ... .",                     // MORSE
//  "-.-. --- -.. .",                       // CODE
//  "-.-. --- -- .--. ..... ----- -----",   // COMP500
//  ". -. ... . ..... ----- .----"          // ENSE501
};

char* code = *morse;
int*p_dots=0;
//int*p_dashes = 0;

analyse(code, p_dots);

printf("Line 1 has %d dots", *p_dots);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are aware `*current + k` is `(*current) + k`, not `*(current + k)`?

Comment: Nope, I saw something about it in the lecture slides and was unsure about what it meant.

Comment: Using the `[]`-operator is the simplest (and with this safest) approach to access an array's element.

Comment: don't use `k`  neither `current` just do `*code++`

Comment: The question is asking to use pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `p_dots++;` is incrementing a pointer, not the dot-count in `main()`.

Comment: I dereferenced p_dots++ but still cannot get it to print.

Comment: You must pass a pointer to `p_dots` to the function, `analyse(code, &p_dots);
`

Comment: Can't alter the code, that function was given. At // TODO: 1) implement the analyse function. This function must take in a Morse code CString as the first parameter, and return, via reference, the number of dashes and dots in the Morse
code C-string. The analyse function must not have any printing or scanning side effects!

Comment: "Pointer arithmetic" is something different - it does not mean "count by using a pointer". And if there are restrictions to what you can do, please put that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all occurrences of this:

```
(*current + k) == '-'
```

to this:

```
*(current + k) == '-'
```

(which means the same as the following:)

```
current[k] = '-'
```

Also in `main()` your code needs to update the value of an `int`, so just create a regular `int`, then pass it's address:

```
int p_dots = 0;
...  
analyse(code, &p_dots);//sends the address so the value can be updated
```

Also, to get all of the values summed properly in the `void analyse(char* code, int* p_dots)` analyze function, a while loop is necessary:  The following is your code with a while loop, and some simplifications:  (it only tracks `p_dots`)

```
void analyse(char* code, int* p_dots)
{
    char *current = code;
    int k = 0;

    while(*current)//check for NULL character
    {
        if (*current == '.')
        {
            (*p_dots)++;
        }
        if (*current  == '-')
        {
            k++;
        }
        if (*current ==' ')
        {
            k++;
        }
        current++; //increment pointer to next position
    }
}
```

By the way, one way to track each of the symbols ( `.`, `-`.  ) is to create a struct, then pass it's address to update the member values.  The example code for this is below:

```
typedef struct {
    int dot;
    int dash;
    int space;
} count_s;

void analyse(char* code, count_s *c)//new prototype to track `.`, `-` and ` `
{
    char *current = code;
    int k = 0;

    while(*current)
    {
        if (*current == '.')
        {
            (*c).dot++;
        }
        if (*current  == '-')
        {
            (*c).dash++;
        }
        if (*current ==' ')
        {
            (*c).space++;
        }
        current++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char* morse[] =
    {
        "... --- ..."                           // SOS
    //  "-- --- .-. ... .",                     // MORSE
    //  "-.-. --- -.. .",                       // CODE
    //  "-.-. --- -- .--. ..... ----- -----",   // COMP500
    //  ". -. ... . ..... ----- .----"          // ENSE501
    };

    char* code = *morse;
    //int p_dots;
    count_s count;
    //int*p_dashes = 0;

    analyse(code, &count);

    printf("Line 1 has %d dots\n", count.dot);
    printf("Line 1 has %d dashes\n", count.dash);
    printf("Line 1 has %d spaces\n", count.space);

    return 0;
}
```

*EDIT* to address question in comments: *How would I go about doing it for the following lines that I've commented out?*

Create an array of string literals

```
 const char *morse[] = {{"... --- ..."},
                   {"-- --- .-. ... ."},
                   {"-.-. --- -.. ."},
                   {"-.-. --- -- .--. ..... ----- -----"},
                   {". -. ... . ..... ----- .----"}};
```

New `main()`...

```
int main(void)
{
    char* code = NULL;//will be used to point to each array line.
    count_s count = {0};//instance of struct with accumulators

    // place declaration of const char *morse[] here as illustrated above

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(morse)/sizeof(morse[0]);i++)
    {
        code = morse[i];//set pointer to successive array elements 0-4
        analyse(code, &count);//count will accumulate values as loop progresses.
    }

    printf(" %d dots\n", count.dot);
    printf(" %d dashes\n", count.dash);
    printf(" %d spaces\n", count.space);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would I go about doing it for the following lines that I've commented out?

Comment: Keep it as an array of string literals (which is what you have), or a 2D array, (either will work)  then loop on each line of the array.  (See Edit and new `main` with loop, read comments for clarifications of what is happening.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void analyse(char *code, int *p_dots, int *p_dashes)
  {
  for( ; *code ; ++code)
    {
    if (*code == '.')
      *p_dots += 1;

    if (*code == '-')
      *p_dashes += 1;
    }
  }

int main(void)
  {
  int dots;
  int dashes;
  char *morse[] =
    {
    "... --- ...",                          // SOS
    "-- --- .-. ... .",                     // MORSE
    "-.-. --- -.. .",                       // CODE
    "-.-. --- -- .--. ..... ----- -----",   // COMP500
    ". -. ... . ..... ----- .----"          // ENSE501
    };

  for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(morse) / sizeof(char *) ; ++i)
    {
    dots = 0;
    dashes = 0;

    analyse(morse[i], &dots, &dashes);

    printf("Line %d ('%s') has %d dots and %d dashes\n", i, morse[i], dots, dashes);
    }

  return 0;
  }
```

A pointer is a variable which contains the address of something. Using a pointer you can look at and/or change the thing it points to. If you increment the *pointer*, you're changing the address in the pointer, and thus you're changing what it points to.

In this code all of the pointer arithmetic is done in the `for` loop `for( ; *code ; ++code)` in the `analyse` function. What we're saying here is that A) there's no initialization section (there's no code before the first `;` in the `for` statement); B) we want to continue as long as what's being pointed at the the `code` pointer is not zero `*code` in the "test" portion of the `for` statement; and C) after each pass through the loop we want to increment the `code` pointer (`++code` in the "increment" section of the `for` statement).

If you wanted to you could replace the `for` loop in `analyse` with:

```
while(*code <> 0)
  {
  if (*code == '.')
    *p_dots += 1;

  if (*code == '-')
    *p_dashes += 1;

  code += 1;
  }
```

When looking at code like this I find it useful to mentally say "object of pointer" whenever I see an asterisk used with a pointer variable - so I'd read the first line of the code above as

```
While object of pointer "code" is not equal to zero...
```

then the next lines read as

```
if object of pointer "code" is equal to the character "period"
  then add one to object of pointer "p_dots"

if object of pointer "code" is equal to the character "dash"
  then add one to object of pointer "p_dashes"

add one to the variable "code"
```

Instead of "object of pointer" maybe you could read it as "target of pointer" to remind yourself that the pointer is pointing to something, and you're manipulating what the pointer points to, or in other words you're manipulating the pointers "target".

I find this kind of thing helps me understand pointer-based code a little bit more. Perhaps that'll help you too.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things up a bit. But now I'm unsure how would I go about including the lines I've commented out. Since the pointer is being incremented, how would I be able to get it to stop at the end of the line and restart the counter again?

Comment: Aside: `sizeof(morse) / sizeof(char *)` --> `sizeof morse / sizeof morse[0]` is less brittle.

Comment: @UltraInstinctMessi - you should do what I did in my example code - you only increment the pointer *after* you've performed all the tests necessary on each individual character.

Comment: @UltraInstinctMessi - I added a bit more explanation of how I read code which uses and manipulates pointers. Perhaps it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

You have issue on the increment of dots and on scanning the string, see `p_dots` update on main.
I change `p_dots` to an int to have it on the stack (should be renamed I think). On your code you need to allocate some memory.

To scan the string:
Just increment the pointer to read char by char in an infinite loop, use a switch for the future of scanning '-', stop on null char.

`code` is pointing to the beginning of the string, `switch (*code++)`  will read the current char and move pointer to the next one.

Start:

```
"... --- ..." 
 ^
 code
```

Read `.` and move code

```
"... --- ..." 
  ^
  code
```

and so on

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void analyse(char* code, int* p_dots)
{
    while (42) {
        switch (*code++) {
          case '.':
            (*p_dots)++;
            break;
          case '-':
            break;
          case '\0':
            return;
          default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char* morse[] =
    {
        "... --- ..."                           // SOS
            //  "-- --- .-. ... .",                     // MORSE
            //  "-.-. --- -.. .",                       // CODE
            //  "-.-. --- -- .--. ..... ----- -----",   // COMP500
            //  ". -. ... . ..... ----- .----"          // ENSE501
    };

    char* code = *morse;
    int p_dots=0;
    //int*p_dashes = 0;

    analyse(code, &p_dots);

    printf("Line 1 has %d dots\n", p_dots);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is asking specifically to use pointer arithmetic. This whole pointer stuff is going over my head =\

Comment: Ok I will add more detail

Comment: Thanks, this whole pointer stuff has been depressed. Spent days on it and just can't grasp it... still have qsort, bsearch, bitwise and binary files to cover..